# What is the bias of uniform distribution parameter estimator?

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

I have a question regarding question 2 of chapter 6 of "All of Statistics" book by Larry Wasserman.

let: $$X_1, ... , X_n \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0, \theta )$$

and let:

$$\hat{\theta} = \max(X_1, ..., X_n)$$

be the estimator of the parameter $\theta$.

My question is that how one can calculate the Expected value of $\hat{\theta}$. My idea is that since the maximum of these random variable is itself a random variable with the uniform distribution mentioned above, the expected value of it will be:

$$E[\hat{\theta}] = E[X_{\max}] = \theta/2$$

However, I was advised that this answer is wrong. Apparently, the correct approach is trying to find the probability distribution function of $\hat{\theta}$ and after doing the algebra, the answer will be:

$$E[\hat{\theta}] = \frac{n}{n+1}.\theta $$

The problem is that I cannot understand the reason that makes my approach wrong. Can anybody illustrate me?

Comment: The maximum of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ does not have the same distribution as the individual random variables.

Comment: @angryavian That is actually correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum of the $X$s is less than 1/2 only if **all** $n$ of the observations are less than 1/2, which happens $1/2^n$ of the time.

In general, $$P(\text{all } x\leq t)=t^n$$ for any $t\in[0,1]$, so the CDF of $\max_n X$ is $F(t)=t^n$ for $t\in[0,1]$.  From that you can work out the mean.